# Typescript Type guards: Using the in operator

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and practicing about Type Guards from [Official DOCS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator)

I'm testing the provided example (more or less) with TypeScript 3.5.3:

```
function exec(strOrNum: string | number) {
    if ("substring" in strOrNum) {
        return strOrNum.substring(1);
    }
    return strOrNum.toExponential(2);
}
```

But VSCode is trowing the following error:

> The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2361)

I don't understand it, any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

This means it operates on objects (or arrays) and not strings.

If you want to add a type guard to differentiate between `string` and `number` you have to use `typeof`:

```js
function exec(strOrNum: string | number) {
    if (typeof strOrNum === "string") {
        return strOrNum.substring(1);
    }
    return strOrNum.toExponential(2);
}
```

You would use the `in` operator if you have a union of two interfaces:

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    b: number;
}


function test(arg: A | B): string {
    if ('a' in arg) {
        return arg.a;
    }
    return arg.b.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately TypeScript 4.1+ still doesn't let use use `typeof` on object members and then safely access those members without an intermediate scalar or using `as any`. Grumble.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to, with TypeScript 4.1.5 it is possible, see the attached playground example, or did you mean something different? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHPQ5EAVwC2AI2g16DGHxAIwwAPYhkkUgAo4UCkXQAfZGwCURUuRAVOeZMBjIVYAJ4AHCHOvqKAOjjIAvL+QByY0p-fXMLPCgIMD4oRTdPGgt6C0jo2PwNT3cwOQAxYAAPCAATFQAmfTEsIA

Comment: that link doesn't work, it gets stuck on "Downloading TypeScript" - I see HTTP 404 errors for https://www.typescriptlang.org/typescript-sandbox/index.js in my dev console - looks like the TypeScript site dun goofed

Comment: this is what I'm referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219385/what-is-the-correct-idiomatic-alternative-to-any-with-typeof-when-writing