# What is the (correct) idiomatic alternative to `any` with `typeof` when writing type-guards?

Tags: typescript, type-safety, typeguards

- Since TypeScript 3.0 introduced the `unknown` *top type* in mid-2018, use of the `any` type is discouraged.
- TypeScript also had had long support for succint type-guards with the `typeof` operator, but `typeof` only works as a first-class type-guard for scalar values (i.e. single variables).

  - The major caveat being that **it cannot be used with object properties or array elements** without first using `as any` or `as T`.

    - Using `as any` has immediately obvious problems.
    - But using `as T` also introduces its own problems. This isn't *that big a problem* inside a type-guard function as the scope of the variable-with-assumed-type is limited to the type-guard, but if used inside a normal function it can introduce bugs.

I'm currently writing client-side error-handling code in TypeScript, in particular, I'm writing an event-listener for `window.error`, which receives an `ErrorEvent` object which in-turn has a member property named `error` which *in practice* could be anything depending on various circumstances.

In TypeScript we need to write top-level functions that serve as runtime and compile-time type-guards. For example, to check if the `window.error` event-listener is really receiving an `ErrorEvent` instead of an `Event` I'd write this:

```
function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    
    // TODO
}

function onWindowError( e: unknown ): void {
    
    if( isErrorEvent( e ) ) {
        // do stuff with `e.error`, etc.
    }
}

window.addEventListener( 'error', onWindowError );
```

My question is about how I'm meant to *idiomatically* implement `isErrorEvent` the way that the TypeScript language designers intend-for. I haven't been able to find any authoritative documentation on the subject.

Specifically, I don't know how I'm supposed to use runtime `typeof` checks to implement `isErrorEvent` without using either a type-assertion to `any` or to the destination type `ErrorEvent`. As far as I know, either of those techniques is required because TypeScript will not let you use `typeof x.y`  when `y` is not part of `x`'s static type - which strikes me as odd because TypeScript *does* let you use `typeof x` when `x` is a scalar of *any* type, not just its static type.

Below, using `as any` works, but I don't like the lack of safety from the `asAny.colno` property dereferences:

```
function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if( !e ) return;
    const asAny = e as any;
    return (
        typeof asAny.colno  === 'number' &&
        typeof asAny.error  === 'object' &&
        typeof asAny.lineno === 'number'
    );
}
```

The alternative is to use `as ErrorEvent`, but I feel that's just as unsafe because TypeScript then *allows* dereferencing of members of `e` *without a prior `typeof` check*!

```
function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if( !e ) return;
    const assumed = e as ErrorEvent;
    return (
        typeof assumed.colno  === 'number' &&
        typeof assumed.error  === 'object' &&
        typeof assumed.lineno === 'number' &&
        
        // For example, TypeScript will not complain about the line below, even though I haven't proved that `e.message` actually exists, just because `ErrorEvent.message` is defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`:
        assumed.message.length > 0
    );
}
```

I suppose what I'm asking is how can I make something like this (see below) work, where TypeScript requires every member be checked with `typeof` before allowing any dereference, and allowing `e` to retain its static-type as `unknown`:

```
function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if( !e ) return;
    return (
        typeof e.colno  === 'number' &&
        typeof e.error  === 'object' &&
        typeof e.lineno === 'number' &&
        
        typeof e.message === 'string' &&
        e.message.length > 0
    );
}
```

...but TypeScript *does* let us do this (see below) which is arguably the same thing, just syntactically far more verbose:

```
function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if( !e ) return;

    const assume = e as ErrorEvent;
    
    if(
        typeof e.colno  === 'number' &&
        typeof e.error  === 'object' &&
        typeof e.lineno === 'number' &&
    )
    {
        const message = assume.message as any;
        return typeof message === 'string' && message.length > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh, this is one of the places where `any` isn't that bad. A type guard often receives *something* and it has to determine whether it fulfills the criteria to be *something else*. You often cannot do that statically, otherwise you don't really need the type guard. There are some instances where you can do this like a union of `A  |  B` and want to type guard for `A` but for arbitrary values it's inherently unsafe. You can type assert `e as Record<string, any>` if it makes you feel safer but I'm not sure there is a convenient way to be completely type safe here.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, but I’m surprised that `typeof x.y` (where `x` is `unknown`) isn’t allowed by TypeScript - so I was wondering if I was overlooking something simple. I suppose I could check for `typeof object` to allow the arbitrary string property indexer to be used though...

Comment: You *can* be more typesafe and satisfy the compiler but IMO it's useless to do that in a typeguard. It leads to comparably uglier code that's only there to satisfy the compiler. [See this example](https://tsplay.dev/PmL7bN). You need a typeguard to tell the compiler that the property you're checking can be checked and then check the property. I find it weird and roundabout.

Answer (score 3):

Type guards are one of the few places I find that `any` is quite acceptable. You have basically two types of type guards based on their parameters

- they take a number of things, usually a union (for example, `A | B | C`) and narrow down the union (for example, to `B`).
- they take a thing that is not well known *what it is* and give it shape.

In the former case, you can easily work within the bounds of the type system to narrow down stuff.

In the latter case, you have a varying amount of "shapelessness" to work with but in extreme cases (like your `unknown`) you have no type support and this leads to something that will look a bit ugly. See here:

```js
type HasProp<T extends object, K extends string> = T & {[P in K]: unknown};

/*
 * type guard to ensure that an arbitrary object has a given property
 */
function hasProp<T extends object, K extends string>(obj: T, prop: K): obj is HasProp<T, K> {
    return prop in obj;
}

function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if( !e ) return false;
    
    if (
        typeof e === "object" && //type guard determines `e` is `object | null`
        e !== null               //type guard to narrow down `e` to only `object`
    ) {
        if (
                hasProp(e, "colno") &&   //type guard to add `colno` to the properties known to be in `e`
                hasProp(e, "error") &&   //type guard to add `error` to the properties known to be in `e`
                hasProp(e, "lineno") &&  //type guard to add `lineno` to the properties known to be in `e`
                hasProp(e, "message")    //type guard to add `message` to the properties known to be in `e`
            ){
                return (
                    typeof e.colno  === 'number' &&
                    typeof e.error  === 'object' &&
                    typeof e.lineno === 'number' &&
                    
                    typeof e.message === 'string' &&
                    e.message.length > 0
                );
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwAoCcD2YA8AVKEAewEAdgCYJRoBGAVhAMbAA0UA0noSeVAsCgJbEA5gD4oAXii4AZFADeAbSRRBbALoAuKAFdiAa2JoA7sQC+AbgBQlgPQAqS1DtRQkKEO1wUpF2jzEEbRRoYAALOGAoOGIolCp+Pi8QSloGSPCKOHd+ADcSKDB0SBRQRzsbSwAzXUZ+NBiM1AwcDiIyCmo6RhZ2AjbuXgFhEQAKTq1sFkKMLVYASi1OlQp4ZCKcHrE5Ryhd4OAgmOmwFRjOq1NrauJa+uWAURR0FHu84mARvC1dA2MYhbwyygj2erxIkW2u12-EqnwAhNA5lB9ocoJU4AAbBAQKxQqA7aGVKAjAl4lzgCBoInQcS0qAAIk6aXpUGkshsNlc0A8Xh8pAgRBQAFtBBAKAADCDioHipmMKAAHygxG0GIx4tJeOgcLpKrVZINeI5XPcnm8vmVXnQRigpD+UEl0uAfnqGOSstSjA1eKRkMNMOJmsNeMaRRGEBY9PoaAxhnpSLZUONFNNvItcFIPnF0djaCdfjC0GOEBK-DFUF+JgtVGgqkdQeDu1DGHDkZLz3jrNku2Tbh55udUUzDvbaBQ+ZcoSLRRLwDLFErMUHNdOI+9jYNzbArYZGNFcYT3d73LNPkHGaze+IJDzFsLBRnpfLi+rtZi9Y3m8QTW3EYZQrFBA4CECBOyTTkU37M8-AvB0AIQICQIne9iyfBdDCrZc3zXBsyTmP1PyhFEUBiElCODLkqTwAA6HNDF2WlJAAchVIUaxQJiu1wwjKOpajRxQBi6SYuVgE4tluM-XiaKvG8JGE1j2PE6RJI3VTG2kiBqPgxCaWEwZBCEZT1ODLSdOArSMRIIQwigMQAAYTKhOZcUNS48XcoiBVRdEsRxSxTCAA)

I want to be clear - all the operations this code does are *correct*. You cannot check if `e` has some arbitrary properties if it is not an object. And checking if an arbitrary property value is a given type is a bit useless without checking if the property exists.

With that said, it is overly verbose and also a bit obtuse.

- The `e !== null` is useless as it's already handled by `!e` in the beginning.
- Checking if a property exists in order to check if its value is a number is directly equivalent to checking if the value is a number. There is usually no difference - if the property doesn't exist of its value is a different type it is all the same in the end.

So, instead of that, I am personally happy to type `e` as `any`. If you want a compromise between *some* type safety and less obtuse code to write, then you can use type it as [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)

```js
function isObj(obj: unknown): obj is Record<PropertyKey, unknown> {
    return typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null;
}

function isErrorEvent( e: unknown ): e is ErrorEvent {
    if ( isObj(e) ) {
        return (
            typeof e.colno  === 'number' &&
            typeof e.error  === 'object' &&
            typeof e.lineno === 'number' &&
            
            typeof e.message === 'string' &&
            e.message.length > 0
        );
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgeQEYCsAUdsBci4A1mHAO5gCUR+WyKiASgKYRwBOAJgDwAKnOAAdWnKAE8A0qwkAaYmDKUwAPkQBvAFCJdiTqyghOSSaLjBE9RAF47iAET12UB4gBk7q9kQBCe2AgADZBANxaAL5aWqCQsAiMAKKcQpyJAG6sYFA4iKxEpORUiLR5jIjJqRlZUJo6ejCWuaiYuKzUJXV63fqGxkg49T09ZqwWeQB0HEHkunY2iADkgQC2GGKLHu5Dw3qj46wTYqlz9ovO0JueO7uI+5aHQTBgWXC2Z6vrnFfbt903u3ukxWrBQKAAhgBzVjvBaLFBQTjPSE-AHDQ4gsFQx5ZSFQAAWiHUAAY0SVwt0ojsDEYTIhgOCgihWOEIkA)

To me the above code is much simpler to read and understand. It is not as rigorously checked by the compiler but it is also completely correct. It's also [acts exactly the same when using `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiKBeKBnYAJwEsA7AcygB8pSBXAWzgkOvxCYHsAbAbgCh+AMzqlUxTqSjE88BAApOiAFxRRAa1KcA7qQCUqpQml4oAQ1JYA3lAD0tgDwBaF09qdg5qACUUnQgAm-FAhUIQQwHSEUqCQnEJQRjjYuABERijAqVAAZDmJiFAAhCm0dNx8-AC+giJiwBJSMgCihIT+zQBuEKTA8lAQqhpaulAGAyZQre2EXT2eVsGhxAn9MnLyEHpjUIuh+2ERUVLySwcHsRDxAwB0yDxaISm4AOT0TCwvuTln56GX1wgNxYMyepReGVQXzyvz+UABCSB3DIPU4yVe72YhGhPzh+1hfwRtwYEDweDM5GgzygLwIJAoOIJ5yBJLJFKRPXIwAAFlAAHxQAAMTLGAn2NV+4Ui0SgQjM3DwEAEVSAA) hence why I don't oppose it. As long as you do the appropriate check that you have an object, it matters little whether it's `Record` or `any`. You're not getting any type support from the compiler either way. The latter is slightly more correct in terms of types but whether that makes a difference is up to you.

---

Note 1: You can also use a type assertion [`e as Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUQE4bhtA3AUzCgApECAuRcAazDgHckBKKg5FRTbXQ4xAN4AoRKOTBEZdgDJpiKAE8ADgTgT2AXi2IARHABGAKwLQdiZoJFjrEBCiiIDhxBvKIAhpwBKJnABMAHgAFbBUMRQBpAgUAGmowOkYwAD4AbitrUQwCKBAMJBIMzOtFFTVHIwA6WwAbelEtVwByMBAAW30CDCbEWSLi0VLVCSdKrp4G7SanEygevoHMofLRmpgwIjgXKdaOrvnpfoGj4uWRqraCFBR3AHNNKfsMdduDk8zRy+u7gkqaoluUAAFohkogAAzvZjpawAXyERWyuXyiGA7hqKAI6VhQA). Doesn't matter much but the additional `isObj` type guard seems more likely to be reused.

---

Note 2: Just for the record, the `hasProp` can be changed to apply to multiple properties. It doesn't solve the core of the issues I have with using it in a type guard but it might still be useful elsewhere:

```js
/*
 * type guard to ensure that an arbitrary object has a given properties
 */
function hasProps<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(obj: T, ...props: K[]): obj is HasProp<T, K> {
    return props.every(prop => prop in obj);
}

/* ... */
if (hasProps(e, "colno", "error", "lineno", "message")) { //type guard to add `colno`, `error`, `lineno`, `message` to the properties known to be in `e`
/* ... */
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-xIcWxXTtUXcxqdQg4J4IKLNsmoJ6+d7lX64KR-Lr84W0LqWPqIWgUMOw5XiCQhyPawh642I4FItA7mMVDqoMizH6qNAvuH7e6WVSUOouafrwSFQK8PMB8YLsLJAByK0ag8oN-S6Qnm8WTvQUHjHFAXxFN8TWAX8ZQAwCLmAh9p1nCRIM-b9YP-BDT3ghCkIgeYFyXIVIIQZI1E8LC8MAwjiIbQi6RITxIigMQAAYaLdX54P+Fk+IJc91FpBkmWscwgA)

Comment: Typescript has `PropertyKey` which is defined the same way as your `ObjectKey`, by the way.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks a lot for that. I never managed to find this type, even though I looked for it. That's quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

> // For example, TypeScript will not complain about the line below, even though I haven't proved that `e.message` actually exists, just because `ErrorEvent.message` is defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`

In cases like this, you should not try to prove, that it's *exactly* an instance of some concrete class, but only define some specific, narrow subset of it's features, that you are actually interested in using, and then type-check for that specific shape.

For example, you aren't really interested, if `e` is an actual `ErrorEvent` instance, you only care if it conforms to some narrow contract:

```js
interface IErrorEvent {
    message: string;
    lineno: number;
    colno: number;
}
```

Now you just need to type-guard for that exact contract.
The best solution for it i came up with is to use an approach, similar to @VLAZ's, just add a generic for inference to `isObj` helper, to get some protection from typos while writing narrowing type-checks themselves:

```
const isLike = <T extends object>(o: unknown): o is Record<keyof T, unknown> => (
    (o ?? false) && typeof o === 'object'
);

const isErrorEvent = (e: unknown): e is IErrorEvent => (
    isLike<IErrorEvent>(e)
        // e at this point is a { message: unknown; lineno: unknown; colno: unknown }, not IErrorEvent or ErrorEvent
        && (typeof e.message === 'string') // ok
        && (typeof e.lineno === 'number') // ok
        && (typeof e.collno === 'number') // TS2551: Property 'collno' does not exist on type 'Record '. Did you mean 'colno'?
);
```